# Getting a NullPointerException at seemingly random intervals, not sure why

Tags: java, processing, kinect

I'm running an example from a Kinect library for Processing (http://www.shiffman.net/2010/11/14/kinect-and-processing/) and sometimes get a NullPointerException pointing to this line:

```
  int rawDepth = depth[offset];
```

The depth array is created in this line:

```
  int[] depth = kinect.getRawDepth();
```

I'm not exactly sure what a NullPointerException is, and much googling hasn't really helped. It seems odd to me that the code compiles 70% of the time and returns the error unpredictably. Could the hardware itself be affecting it?

Here's the whole example if it helps:

```
// Daniel Shiffman
// Kinect Point Cloud example
// http://www.shiffman.net
// https://github.com/shiffman/libfreenect/tree/master/wrappers/java/processing

import org.openkinect.*;
import org.openkinect.processing.*;

// Kinect Library object
Kinect kinect;

float a = 0;

// Size of kinect image
int w = 640;
int h = 480;


// We'll use a lookup table so that we don't have to repeat the math over and over
float[] depthLookUp = new float[2048];

void setup() {
  size(800,600,P3D);
  kinect = new Kinect(this);
  kinect.start();
  kinect.enableDepth(true);
  // We don't need the grayscale image in this example
  // so this makes it more efficient
  kinect.processDepthImage(false);

  // Lookup table for all possible depth values (0 - 2047)
  for (int i = 0; i < depthLookUp.length; i++) {
    depthLookUp[i] = rawDepthToMeters(i);
  }
}

void draw() {

  background(0);
  fill(255);
  textMode(SCREEN);
  text("Kinect FR: " + (int)kinect.getDepthFPS() + "\nProcessing FR: " + (int)frameRate,10,16);

  // Get the raw depth as array of integers
  int[] depth = kinect.getRawDepth();
  // We're just going to calculate and draw every 4th pixel (equivalent of 160x120)
  int skip = 4;

  // Translate and rotate
  translate(width/2,height/2,-50);
  rotateY(a);

  for(int x=0; x<w; x+=skip) {
    for(int y=0; y<h; y+=skip) {
      int offset = x+y*w;
      // Convert kinect data to world xyz coordinate
      int rawDepth = depth[offset];
      PVector v = depthToWorld(x,y,rawDepth);

      stroke(255);
      pushMatrix();
      // Scale up by 200
      float factor = 200;
      translate(v.x*factor,v.y*factor,factor-v.z*factor);
      // Draw a point
      point(0,0);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }

  // Rotate
  a += 0.015f;
}

// These functions come from: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/Kinect.html
float rawDepthToMeters(int depthValue) {
  if (depthValue < 2047) {
    return (float)(1.0 / ((double)(depthValue) * -0.0030711016 + 3.3309495161));
  }
  return 0.0f;
}

PVector depthToWorld(int x, int y, int depthValue) {

  final double fx_d = 1.0 / 5.9421434211923247e+02;
  final double fy_d = 1.0 / 5.9104053696870778e+02;
  final double cx_d = 3.3930780975300314e+02;
  final double cy_d = 2.4273913761751615e+02;

  PVector result = new PVector();
  double depth =  depthLookUp[depthValue];//rawDepthToMeters(depthValue);
  result.x = (float)((x - cx_d) * depth * fx_d);
  result.y = (float)((y - cy_d) * depth * fy_d);
  result.z = (float)(depth);
  return result;
}

void stop() {
  kinect.quit();
  super.stop();
}
```

And here are the errors:

```
processing.app.debug.RunnerException: NullPointerException
    at processing.app.Sketch.placeException(Sketch.java:1543)
    at processing.app.debug.Runner.findException(Runner.java:583)
    at processing.app.debug.Runner.reportException(Runner.java:558)
    at processing.app.debug.Runner.exception(Runner.java:498)
    at processing.app.debug.EventThread.exceptionEvent(EventThread.java:367)
    at processing.app.debug.EventThread.handleEvent(EventThread.java:255)
    at processing.app.debug.EventThread.run(EventThread.java:89)
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openkinect.processing.Kinect.enableDepth(Kinect.java:70)
    at PointCloud.setup(PointCloud.java:48)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1583)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1503)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Comment: I think you need to look at the possibility that `getRawDepth()` is returning `null` instead of an array.

Comment: @Falmarri I pasted the errors

@Asaph Yeah, I thought so too. I don't know how to test if the variable is null in Processing.

Comment: Would the solution be to create a conditional to only assign rawDepth to depth[offset] if getRawDepth() isn't null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a NullPointerException since the value of the depth array is null.  You can see from the source code of the Kinect class, there is a chance of a null value being returned by the getRawDepth() method.  It is likely that there is no image being displayed at the time.

The code can be found at:

https://github.com/shiffman/libfreenect/blob/master/wrappers/java/processing/KinectProcessing/src/org/openkinect/processing/Kinect.java

Your code should check if the depth array is null before trying to process it.  For example...

```
int[] depth = kinect.getRawDepth();

if (depth == null) {
  // do something here where you handle there being no image
} else {
  // We're just going to calculate and draw every 4th pixel (equivalent of 160x120)
  int skip = 4;

  // Translate and rotate
  translate(width/2,height/2,-50);
  rotateY(a);

  for(int x=0; x<w; x+=skip) {
    for(int y=0; y<h; y+=skip) {
      int offset = x+y*w;
      // Convert kinect data to world xyz coordinate
      int rawDepth = depth[offset];
      PVector v = depthToWorld(x,y,rawDepth);

      stroke(255);
      pushMatrix();
      // Scale up by 200
      float factor = 200;
      translate(v.x*factor,v.y*factor,factor-v.z*factor);
      // Draw a point
      point(0,0);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }

  // Rotate
  a += 0.015f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a Java Debugger so that you can see the state of the variables at the time the exception is thrown.  Some people also like to use log statements to output the values of the variables at different points in the application.

You can then trace the problem back to a point where one of the values is not populated with a non-null value.

Answer (score 1):

The null pointer is happening when offset > kinect.getRawDepth();

You have a lot of code here, I'm not going to look at it all. Why can you assume that offset is < kinect.getRawDepth()?

*Edit*:

On second though, @Asaph's comment is probably right.

Answer (score 1):

Null Pointer exception happens when `depth[offset]` does not exist or has not been allocated. Check when `depth[offset]` is undefined and that is the cause of the nullpointer exception.

Check when `kinect.getRawDepth();` is greater than `offset`.